# Bootstrap Affix Padding Causing elements to shift

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a problem with my **affix + container** padding value causing some elements directly below it to move when I click on them.

My css code:

```
.affix {
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index:99;
}
.affix + #container-fluid-main {
  padding-top: 70px;
}
```

I have a slideshow under my navigation bar where my navigation bar is fixed at the top (mobile screens). Now when I click on the slideshow to change an image the entire slideshow shifts down and there's a whitespace between the navigation bar and the slideshow.

I traced my problem to be that the slideshow has no margin-top so the padding-top value from the `affix + #container-fluid-main` causes the slideshow to shift. How can i overcome this without adding a top margin to the slideshow and keeping the smooth transition of the navigation bar? Thanks

Before Image
[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbFLr.png)

And After I click on the image directly under the navigation bar
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HB4Yc.png)

Comment: You need to post a minimal working example that demonstrates your issue (HTML/CSS/JS) see [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: @vanburen I have added some images that show my problem